# Seeing only one endpoint in browsable API instead of two

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How come I can only see one of my URLs (`users`) instead of both in the django rest browsable API?

[image]

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),
    path("", include("accounts.urls")),
    path("", include("properties.urls")),
]
```

I expected to see `users` AND `properties`

accounts.urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from accounts.views import UserViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"users", UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [path("", include(router.urls))]
```

properties.urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from properties.views import PropertyViewSet, UnitViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"properties", PropertyViewSet)
router.register(r"units", UnitViewSet)

urlpatterns = [path("", include(router.urls))]
```

Comment: Is there authentication token for API which are not getting listed?

Comment: Both paths match the exact same thing, could you try giving each include a unique path and see if that changes anything?

Comment: @IainShelvington so if I add something to one of the paths, then the other "empty" path should show. However, I thought if i left both empty, then both urls would be displayed. It just seems as though the first MATCHING url is displayed and not both